# ALTER TABLE...ADD not working in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, alter-table

I'm trying to alter a table by adding a new column inside a stored procedure. Here's what I have:

```
USE [Lab5]
go
create procedure do_ver2 as
    alter table VehicleContract
        add trailerNr varchar(7) null;
    alter table VehicleContract
        add constraint FK_VehicleContract_Trailers foreign key (trailerNr) references Trailers(trailerNr);
go
```

The problem is... although it doesn't show any errors, it also doesn't create a new column either. Any idea why? It's T-SQL.

Comment: Why are you trying put ddl inside a procedure? What do you think will happen if you run this procedure a second time?

Comment: Honestly, I'm just doing what they shown me at the course

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Then get through the class and immediately forget about this as it is a very poor example. Doing this in a stored procedure kind of negates the whole concept of code reuse when you can't call it more than once.

Comment: I tried adding a begin and end to the whole thing and run it as it is and it worked. Is it ok?

Comment: Sure but that isn't because of adding begin and end. Keep in mind that in the real world you do not want to modify tables from a stored procedure. It just doesn't make sense. It is ok for class though so you can learn how this stuff works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Dynamic-SQL to execute DDL statement inside stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE do_ver2 AS
BEGIN
    EXEC('alter table VehicleContract add trailerNr varchar(7) null;');
    EXEC('alter table VehicleContract add constraint FK_VehicleContract_Trailers foreign key (trailerNr) references Trailers(trailerNr);');
END
GO
```

**EDIT:**

In your code without `BEGIN` and `END` your stored procedure contain only first statement. You should always add begin/end block.

```
USE [Lab5]
go
create procedure do_ver2 as
    EXEC('alter table VehicleContract
        add trailerNr varchar(7) null;');
    EXEC('alter table VehicleContract
        add constraint FK_VehicleContract_Trailers 
        foreign key (trailerNr) references Trailers(trailerNr);');
go
```

If you check the the code of stored procedure you will see that it have only:

```
 create procedure do_ver2 as
        EXEC('alter table VehicleContract add trailerNr varchar(7) null;');
```

Comment: There's no way for me to alter a table without dynamic sql?

Comment: @Charlotte45  Inside stored procedure there is no way to DDL without Dynamic-SQL

Comment: So I made my code work by adding a begin and and inside the procedure. I have no idea why it works but it did